# Class add property on all objects in python

Tags: python, function, class, properties, initialization

I found an issue while programming on python. I have the class Dinero (money in english) which has all properties for the currency in DnD.

```
class Dinero:
    
    def __init__(self, copper_pieces, silver_pieces, electrum_pieces, gold_pieces, platinum_pieces) -> None:
        self.copper_pieces = copper_pieces
        self.silver_pieces = silver_pieces
        self.electrum_pieces = electrum_pieces
        self.gold_pieces = gold_pieces
        self.platinum_pieces = platinum_pieces
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "Dinero obtenido:\n  Copper: "+str(self.copper_pieces)+"\n  Silver: "+str(self.silver_pieces)+"\n  Electrum: "+str(self.electrum_pieces)+"\n  Gold: "+str(self.gold_pieces)+"\n  Platinum: "+str(self.platinum_pieces)

    def add_gold(self, gold):
        self.gold_pieces += gold

    def agregar_dinero(self, dinero):
        self.copper_pieces += dinero.copper_pieces
        self.silver_pieces += dinero.silver_pieces
        self.electrum_pieces += dinero.electrum_pieces
        self.gold_pieces += dinero.gold_pieces
        self.platinum_pieces += dinero.platinum_pieces
```

Then I have my class named Mochila (bag in english) which has a list of items and a Dinero class.

```
import dinero

class Mochila:

    def __init__(self, dinero:dinero.Dinero=dinero.Dinero(0,0,0,0,0), items:list=[]):
        self.items = items
        self.dinero = dinero
    
    def meter_item(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
    
    def sacar_item(self, item):
        self.items.remove(item)
```

In my main I set 2 different mochila's and the mochila2 is taking the value of the mochila1's Dinero.

```
import dinero
import mochila


mochila1 = mochila.Mochila()
mochila2 = mochila.Mochila()

print(mochila2.dinero)

nuevo_dinero = dinero.Dinero(10, 10,200,10,10)

print(mochila2.dinero)

mochila1.dinero.agregar_dinero(nuevo_dinero)

print(mochila2.dinero)

mochila2.dinero.agregar_dinero(mochila1.dinero)
mochila1.dinero = dinero.Dinero(0,0,0,0,0)
```

Why is this happening and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it looks like both dinero instances are the same, as in if you comment out your **str** method, you will see they take up the exact same space in memory, so with:

```
print(mochila2.dinero)
print(mochila1.dinero)
```

You get back:

```
<__main__.Dinero object at 0x0000025D90EC0B08>
<__main__.Dinero object at 0x0000025D90EC0B08>
```

This is because when you set the default dinero in mochila's constructor, it is using the same default every time, not creating a new instance each time. To fix this, and considering you probably always want a new mochila to start of with 0 money anyway, try jus moving the instantiation of dinero to the constructor:

```
class Mochila:

    def __init__(self, items: list=[]):
        self.items = items
        self.dinero = Dinero(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```